# Twitter basic authorisation not working?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, twitter, basic-authentication

```
URL url = new URL("http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);

String cridentials =
    new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode((username + ":" + password).getBytes());

conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + cridentials);

OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(status);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

Why is above code for updating twitter status is not working ?

I am running it on google app engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find this easier if you the [java twitter library](http://code.google.com/p/java-twitter/). Even if you don't use it, you can read it and see how to do this much more straightforwardly with Apache Commons Http Client.

Comment: It's just a jar file. I don't see why not, but I'm never used it.

Comment: This project seems to have lapsed; not sure that it supports OAuth.